# I'm looking for a way to add database update scripts to a "playlist"

Tags: database, scripting

I've got a group of scripts to run and I'd like to batch them all together. Rather than write a .cmd/.bat file to run the lot it feels to me like there ought to be something similar to a playlist (e.g. .pls ?) file and 'script player' that could run each script in order and have different options on what to do if a script fails (e.g. stop / carry-on). Sort of like a makefile I guess only a bit more user friendly.

Please can you point me at anything like this? thanks.

Comment: There is a fine line between what you are asking for and outright suggestions for software, which would not be a good fit for this website... You might want to edit the question to sound more like you are looking for a solution to your problem (dealing with database changes) instead of specific software to do that.

Comment: Something I hadn't though about until I saw Robbie Dee's answer: what exactly is your use case? To me this seems to be about updates to the database as part of an application update process, but what you need obviously varies depending on what the context is.

Comment: @JDT basically, we're sending a bunch of scripts out to a customer and we need them to run them in order. Usually we just tell them to do this but we've been trying to tighten the process so that they don't ignore errors or keep on repeatedly running the same failing script and it occurred to me that running scripts in order superficially was similar to playing music in order and I wondered if there was an industry standard tool or way of doing this.

Comment: Could you edit the question to put that in? The fact that the customer has to run these is actually very relevant... Also, you should edit the question as describe in the 'on hold'-message so you don't actually ask for a tool...

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a *database change management system*. Depending on your evironment you might be looking at manually writing scripts, but there are also [frameworks that can do migrations with code](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

There are many different software solutions that help you with this issue and you can look them up with your favorite search engine. For example, the company I work for uses [RoundhousE](https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for an [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) tool such as [SSIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services).

These are tools that support the extraction, transformation and loading of data into data warehouses. Whilst this may not be *exactly* what you're probably trying to do, they do have extensive functionality for running scripts and you are able to branch accordingly depending on a variety of criteria.